# SSRS integration with Post Gre

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I am using SSRS for reports and am connecting to Post gre  sql.
I have written a procedure to retrieve the records.
While creating the report, I get a drop down that asks me to select the procedure I want to run. However it does not show the list of procedures in my post gre sql database.
Is this an issue with the grant that is given on a procedure? please advice.

I have tried this with sql/Oracle and it works. 
However, with post gre, it doesnt work.

Thanks!

Comment: Could be privileges. But are there any procedures *in* the PostgreSQL database? How do you know?

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of procedures in the post gre sql database. I am not able to see any of it in the drop down.

Comment: What kind of privileges? If the procedure can be seen in the drop down when connected to a oracle/sql db, what specific grants may be required when it comes to post gre?

Comment: For example, if you were to `revoke usage on schema public from public;` a user that derives its privileges from membership in the group "public" wouldn't be able to see any tables, views, etc that are stored in the "public" schema.  Examine in pgAdminIII, or use `\dp` in psql.